How can I run a Python script that takes command line arguments from another Python script that I am writing?
I have a python 3 script that looks like:
  ...

  def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Perform normalisation checks on pass2 files')
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--parser', action='store', help='parser_code.', default="")
    parser.add_argument('-m', '--midnight', help='start of day '
                        'in ns UTC', type=int, default=0)

    parser.add_argument('file', help='File to validate')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    rc = ReturnCode.SUCCESS

    rc = do_checks(args.file, args.midnight, args.parser)
    print(f"Validation completed with status: {rc}")

    exit(rc)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Normally I would run this script, on the command line, passing in a filename as an argument, so something like:
python3 /util/check_normalisation.py -p lse /home/pchong/work/algotick/new_lob/pass2/01/97756_20240701.h5

However, now I have a directory full of files (thousands of files) that I would like to run this script against.
And I'm finding it challenging to 'run this script' from another script that I create. Is it possible to do this?
Here is the outline of my script:
    directory = '<path_to_directory_with_files_I_would_like_to_run_script_against'
 
    for file in os.listdir(directory):
        filename = os.fsdecode(file)

        run_the_above_script(filename)  # this is where I don't know what to do to run the command line python script


Take a look at the subprocess module

Why not making your original main function to take arguments and use argparse to feed those arguments only if __name__ == '__main__'?

Gotcha, didn't think of that. Thank you. The only thing is that if I have thousands of files, I would feed all those filesnames as argumnets?

You feed those arguments (e.g. filename) in your for loop: your desired run_the_above_script(filename) would become main(filename) (with a better name maybe). In this way your original script can work both as a module or a standalone program.

You can use subprocess.run for this. Example:
import subprocess

subprocess.run(["python", "script_name.py", "arg1", "arg2", ...])

You can checkout Python's subprocess management docs here.

I suggest to improve your script so it would be able to accept multiple files and do what it is supposed to do in sequence. You might use nargs='+' in argparse to express one or more, consider following simple example, let fnprinter.py be
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Filenames printer")
parser.add_argument("--prefix", help="will be printed before each filename", default="")
parser.add_argument("files", help="filenames", nargs="+")
args = parser.parse_args()
for file in args.files:
    print(args.prefix, file)

then
python fnprinter.py --prefix foobar file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt

gives output
foobar file1.txt
foobar file2.txt
foobar file3.txt


Although your suggestion is an improvment on the original design, it does not answer the question

Thanks for this! I can see the design improvement here. The only thing is that if I have thousands of files, I wouldn't know how to pass those in, unless I manually typed each one out
